# Differentiating $0.5\sin⁡(2t-\pi/2)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I now have a fine understanding of how to differentiate simple functions such as where $48x^2$ or $4x$ or a simple constant.  I have a small problem finding information regarding how to do this task though.  Do i simply end up with

$0.5\cos(2- ....$  I believe this part would be correct but am lost with the - $\pi/2$ part.

$i=0.5\sin⁡(2t-π/2)$  ($t$ is measured in radians)

the question wants to produce an equation that describes the rate of change of current (i).  I assume I am on the right track but just getting lost half way?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Is this referring to some other question/answer on SE? Taken by itself it seems to be missing some context.

Comment: What function are you trying to differentiate?

Comment: When you derivate a circular function, the phase remains the same (the equation that describes the change you want to calculate is $di/dt = 2\cdot 0.5 \cos(2t - \pi/2) = \cos (2t - \pi/2)$)

Comment: The current, i of an electrical circuit varies over time, and is given by the relationship

 i=0.5sin⁡(2t-π/2) ,where t is measured in radians.
Produce an equation that describes the rate of change of current.

This is the entire text i have on the question, have i missed the point completely and confused

Comment: Part of your misunderstanding might be related to your calling *48x^2* a FUNCTION - it is an *expression*. $$f(x) = 48x^2$$ is a function! The function you're given is a few steps away. First, it's a more complicated function. Second, the variable is different, which might trip you up.

Answer (score 3):

If you have $$i(t) = 0.5 \sin (2t-\pi/2)$$ then
$$
\begin{split}
i'(t) &= \frac{d}{dt} \left[ 0.5 \sin (2t-\pi/2) \right] \\
      &= 0.5 \frac{d}{dt} \left[ \sin (2t-\pi/2) \right] \\
      &= 0.5 \cos (2t-\pi/2) \frac{d[ 2t-\pi/2]}{dt} \\
      &= 0.5 \cos (2t-\pi/2) \cdot 2 \\
      &= \cos (2t-\pi/2)
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend getting comfortable with the Chain Rule,
which is used in the answer by @gt6989b.

In this particular case, however, there is a simplification you can make that avoids having to explicitly apply the Chain Rule:

$$ \sin\left(\theta - \frac\pi2\right)
 = -\sin\left(\frac\pi2 - \theta\right)
 = -\cos(\theta).
$$

(More generally, whenever you add any multiple of $\frac\pi2$ to the parameter of a sine or cosine function, the result will be equal to a sine, cosine, negative sine, or negative cosine of the same parameter without the added multiple of $\frac\pi2$.
In this case the multiple of $\frac\pi2$ is $-\frac\pi2$.
You may find it easier to work out the relationships graphically on a unit circle than to do it algebraically as I did above.)

Set $\theta = 2t$. Then

$$ \sin\left(2t - \frac\pi2\right) = -\cos(2t).$$

I think you know how to differentiate that.